# << operator overloading returning null on using destructor

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, destructor

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


class MyString{

private:
 char *str=new char[10];

public:
    MyString(){*str='\0';}           //default constructor
    MyString(char *s){               //parameterized constructor
    str=s;
}

private:
int length(char* s){
    int i=0;
    while(s[i]!='\0')
        i++;
return i;
}
char* delchar(char* s,int count,int start){
    int i,j=0;
    char *temp= new char[10];
    for(i=start;i<start+count;i++){
        s[i]=' ';
    }
    for(i=0;i<length(s);i++){
        if(s[i]!=' ')
            temp[j++]=s[i];
    }
    s=temp;
    return s;
}

public:
MyString operator-(MyString s){
    int i=0,j=0,count=0,start=-1;/* i to iterate the first string,j to iterate the     second string*/
    MyString temp;              /*  count to count the matched characters ,start to know the starting index*/
    temp.str=str;

    while(temp.str[i]!='\0'){
        j=0;
        start++;
        while(s.str[j]!='\0'){
            if(temp.str[i]==s.str[j]){
                count++;
                i++;
                j++;
                if(count==length(s.str)){//checks if the count
                    temp.str=delchar(temp.str,count,start);
                    i=i-count;
                    start=i-1;
                    count=0;
                }
            }
            else{
                i++;
                count=0;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    return temp;
}
~MyString(){
    delete str;
}

friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream,MyString& s){
    stream<<s.str<<endl;
    return stream;
}

};
int main(){
char *p= new char[20];
char *q= new char[10];

cin>>p;
cin>>q;

MyString s1(p);
MyString s2(q);
MyString s3;

s3=s1-s2;
cout<<s3;
delete p;
delete q;
return 0;
}
```

The above code overloads the - operator .It tries to subtract the substring from the main string for example input1:joshmathews input2:josh output:mathews. I am trying to store the output in a new MyString object s3. When I use a destructor as shown above,outputting s3
returns null. But when I don't use a destructor I get the expected output.Can anyone help?

Comment: Please learn about constructor initializer lists. This code has a horrible, horrible memory error.

Comment: Also please learn about std::string, after all this is supposed to be c++

Comment: Function `delchar` is completely "off the hook" man.

Comment: It is hard to cover the amount of errors in this code. The `MyString(char *s)` constructor in its current implementation is bound to cause a runtime error at some point. You should change it to something like: `str = new char[strlen(s)+1]; strcpy(str,s);`.

Comment: tmp.str=str is the culprit ! Guess what happens to the ptr when tmp goes out of scope ...

Comment: `std::regex_replace(p, std::regex{q}, "");`

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue is that Operater- returns a local object which is copied by a default copy constructor -- that default copy constructor points s3 to the exact same memory/buffer of the temp MyString, and when that temp is destructed, it wipes out the memory s3 is using.

That is referred to as a dangling pointer. You can read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer#Cause_of_wild_pointers

The code below is the changes I made to get your program executing and returning a valid result, while completing without error. To be clear though, there are issues with this altered version, runtime error or no runtime error, but this will help illuminate some important points.

When you define a type that allocates memory, you've really started to do somethings that don't come free. My altered version below completely got rid of the destructor, so actually it leaks memory up until the program ends. The destructor was invalid though, so removing it allowed the program the finish. But this would be one of those things that in general you shouldn't just accept.

I added a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator:

```
MyString(const MyString& s) {
    strcpy_s(str, 10, s.str);
}

MyString& operator=(const MyString& s) {
    strcpy_s(str, 10, s.str);
    return *this;
}
```

Notice the strcpy_s in both of these. What is doing is copy the character string from the argument instead of just trying to point at the exact same string at the exact same address as the argument. If the argument gets destructed in your version, it wipes out some memory, so we can just accept default copy constructor and such since by default they are shallow copies that point to the same guts. That's one of the burdens of allocating memory -- you need to take care of that in both your destructor's ~and~ some of your constructors. This is referred to as "The Rule of Three":

**If you need to explicitly declare either the destructor, copy constructor or copy assignment operator yourself, you probably need to explicitly declare all three of them.**

Here's a wikipedia link about the rule of three: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)

You needed a destructor, so that's the clue you need the others. The reason is as I was saying -- by default you get a copy constructor for free, but it just makes everything point to the same guts if there are points are resources, but then you can't delete one without affecting everybody else.

Also, in delchar I added this line towards the bottom:

```
temp[j] = '\0';
```

Characters strings must always end at a null, and you copied only actual letter characters into temp, so without a null character, a strcpy doesn't know where to end.

If you remember I yanked out your destructor, then those are the changes I made.

The destructor also has an issue, in that if you use new to create an array, like

```
char* c = new char[10];
```

then you need to delete it in a way that indicates in was new'd as an array, like so:

```
delete [] c;
```

The next thing you should look into is how your MyString construction happens. If you step through, you'll see that the str member get new'd -- that means it holds a valid address into a buffer you can use -- but then if the MyString(char *s) constructor is used, it literally just takes this new address of s, and makes str hold that address instead -- which means the old address pointing to the valid buffer is lost, and that buffer of new'd memory cannot be freed. So that's a leak. You could use the strcpy_s strategy from the constructors I added to copy the contexts of what is pointed to by the s in MyString(char *s) into the new'd buffer. That would make a huge positive difference in the code.

And don't bother about all the elitists out there -- many of them were born doing headstands, so they can't see to relate to newbies giving things an honest effort.

Here's the full altered code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyString{

private:
    char *str = new char[10];

public:
    MyString(){ *str = '\0'; }           //default constructor
    MyString(char *s){               //parameterized constructor
        str = s;
    }
    MyString(const MyString& s) {
        strcpy_s(str, 10, s.str);
    }
    MyString& operator=(const MyString& s) {
        strcpy_s(str, 10, s.str);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    int length(char* s){
        int i = 0;
        while (s[i] != '\0')
            i++;
        return i;
    }
    char* delchar(char* s, int count, int start){
        int i, j = 0;
        char *temp = new char[10];
        for (i = start; i<start + count; i++){
            s[i] = ' ';
        }
        for (i = 0; i<length(s); i++){
            if (s[i] != ' ')
                temp[j++] = s[i];
        }
        temp[j] = '\0';
        s = temp;
        return s;
    }

public:
    MyString operator-(MyString s){
        int i = 0, j = 0, count = 0, start = -1;/* i to iterate the first string,j to iterate the     second string*/
        MyString temp;              /*  count to count the matched characters ,start to know the starting index*/
        temp.str = str;

        while (temp.str[i] != '\0'){
            j = 0;
            start++;
            while (s.str[j] != '\0'){
                if (temp.str[i] == s.str[j]){
                    count++;
                    i++;
                    j++;
                    if (count == length(s.str)){//checks if the count
                        temp.str = delchar(temp.str, count, start);
                        i = i - count;
                        start = i - 1;
                        count = 0;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    i++;
                    count = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        return temp;
    }
    ~MyString(){
        //delete str;
    }

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, MyString& s){
        stream << s.str << endl;
        return stream;
    }

};
int main(){
    char *p = new char[20];
    char *q = new char[10];

    cin >> p;
    cin >> q;

    MyString s1(p);
    MyString s2(q);
    MyString s3;

    s3 = s1 - s2;
    cout << s3;
    delete p;
    delete q;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thamk you very much ! It helped a lot